# Bootstrap and multiple select controls inline too big

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and I'm looking to have 2 list boxes next to each other (one represents month the other year) and 2 buttons that move the selected month/year to another list box. When I place all of this in my page it's too wide (the list boxes are way to wide for what's needed). How can I get these list boxes to be less in width, but the same height and look as a normal bootstrap form-control list box?

```
<div class="form-inline">
            <label for="selectMonth" class="control-label col-md-5">Period:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7" style="display:inline">

                <select id="selectMonth" class="form-control" size="4">
                    <option>Jan</option>
                    <option>Feb</option>
                    <option>Mar</option>
                    <option>Apr</option>
                    <option>May</option>
                    <option>Jun</option>
                    <option>Jul</option>
                    <option>Aug</option>
                    <option>Sep</option>
                    <option>Oct</option>
                    <option>Nov</option>
                    <option>Dec</option>
                </select>

                <select id="selectYear" class="form-control" size="4">

                </select>

                <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="buttonMoveAll">>></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="buttonMoveOne">></button>
                </div>

                <select id="selectFinal" class="form-control" size="4">

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytvLX/8/)

```
<div class="form-inline col-md-10">
    <label for="selectMonth" class="control-label col-md-2">Period:</label>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="display:inline">
        <select id="selectMonth" class="form-control" size="4">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
            <option>Apr</option>
            <option>May</option>
            <option>Jun</option>
            <option>Jul</option>
            <option>Aug</option>
            <option>Sep</option>
            <option>Oct</option>
            <option>Nov</option>
            <option>Dec</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="display:inline"> 
        <select id="selectYear" class="form-control" size="4"></select>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="buttonMoveAll">>></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="buttonMoveOne">></button>
        </div>
        <select id="selectFinal" class="form-control" size="4"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```